# Gradle stack trace on terminal

Tags: unit-testing, logging, gradle

I'm required to use Gradle for my Java project.
I'm running some unit tests with `./gradlew test`, but the exception stack trace is witten on a **web page** which I need to load in a browser.

Why such complication?

Is there a way of getting it on the terminal instead, as I Maven does?

Comment: Two years later, I got my attention here because of up-votes, and I still get horrified by the idea of a stack-trace on a webpage. What the hell were they thinking?

Answer (score 27):

According to [this page](http://mrhaki.blogspot.se/2013/05/gradle-goodness-show-more-information.html) the following will do:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
}
```

This is actually working. It's not really showing the whole exception trace, but (even better?) it shows the **relevant part of it** (that is, the part associated to the code written in the unittest).

The equivalent of the above in `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  testLogging { exceptionFormat = org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat.FULL }
}
```

Comment: Strangely, if you also also include `events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"` in the testLogging section, the full stack traces are not available anymore.  I'm using Gradle 5.0.  Seems like you can either have a full stack trace using the option in your answer above OR you can include the `events` option, but not both.

Comment: When using Gradle 5.6.4, the exception trace did not show up in the console, with the above configuration. I discovered I had a leftover plugin that I needed to remove from the build.gradle file. Make sure you have removed any references to ´com.adarshr.test-logger´. It's not needed.

Answer (score 3):

For gradle (kotlin dsl) you could do this:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat

tasks {
  test {
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
        showStackTraces = true
        exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what does events() do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me in the **Android** project.
To module level `build.gradle` file (such as `app/build.gradle`), add the following lines:

```
plugins {
    // ...
}

android {
    // ...
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'

        // Optionally do:
        showStackTraces = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
}
```