# SQLite database in CI/CD pipeline of Bitbucket "Unable to open the database file"

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, gradle, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

In my Spring boot project (Using gradle as build tool), I'm using SQLite database. The database file is located under `/db/` directory of project root:

```
my-project/
 - db/
    - mydb.db  ## This db file is generated by JPA when run the project
 - src/
    - main
      - java/
        ...
 - bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

In my `src/main/resouces/application.yml` I have:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlite:file:./db/mydb.db?cache=shared
    driver-class-name: org.sqlite.JDBC
    username: foo
    password: foo
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

The folder `/db/` under project root is actually empty at first, When run this project locally, the database file `mydb.db` is created **automatically** by JPA. The application works fine too locally, the database connection is established.

Now I want to build the project in CI/CD pipeline. In my simple `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`, I only have the step to build the project:

```
image: gradle:7.6.0-jdk17

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-it
        name: Build project
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - bash ./gradlew build
        artifacts:
          - 'build/**'
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build-it
```

After pushed the code to bitbucket repository, the pipeline is triggered, but it ends up with error saying unable to open the database file. Since the full stack trace is too long, I included the most interesting lines below:

```
> Task :test
MyApplicationTests > testRestEndpoint() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3fb1948c testClass = com.foo.MyApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.foo.MyApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@4b3fa0b3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6e950bcf, [ImportsContextCustomizer@7c39193f key = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@50468873, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2a898881, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@497486b3, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@5b1a990f], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
        
...
...
  Caused by:
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [[SQLITE_CANTOPEN] Unable to open the database file (unable to open database file)] [n/a]
            at a
...
...
Caused by:
            jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [[SQLITE_CANTOPEN] Unable to open the database file (unable to open database file)] [n/a]
...
...
Caused by:
                org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [[SQLITE_CANTOPEN] Unable to open the database file (unable to open database file)] [n/a]
...
...
  Caused by:
                    org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CANTOPEN] Unable to open the database file (unable to open database file)
                        at app//org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1179)

...
...
```

It looks like my pipeline can not open the SQLite database file.

Could someone please guide me how to refactor my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` to make the database file be accessible by the pipeline?

Comment: If you run the same integration test that fails on your CI/CD locally, is the DB created successfully by Hibernate? Please post the full exception you get with its stacktrace to see the root cause.

Comment: @dekkard, I updated my post with the full exception, I think the exception means the DB is not created.

Comment: You might need to enable full stack traces to see the actual error as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350802/gradle-stack-trace-on-terminal Also, what about my first question on running the same test locally?

Comment: @dekkard, I mentioned in my post that running locally the database is created automatically under the db/ folder (which was an empty folder before running the project).  Thanks for the link, I now updated the full stack trace again.

Comment: @dekkard, with the full stack trace, it is clear to me that the problem is that the pipeline is not able to open the database file `mydb.db`, that causes the test failure. But how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering [SQLite databases](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) (Unlike a traditional SQL database) are [file-based](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5), they require that the directory in which the database file resides must be writable by the user running the application.

You can try and  modify your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` to create explicitly the `./db` folder, for testing:

```yaml
image: gradle:7.6.0-jdk17

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-it
        name: Build project
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - pwd  # Print the current working directory for debugging
          - mkdir -p ./db  # Explicitly create the db directory
          - chmod 755 ./db  # Make sure the directory is writable
          - bash ./gradlew build  # Now run your build
        artifacts:
          - 'build/**'
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build-it
```

Check then if that pipeline is able to create the SQLite database file within the `/db` directory. (You can try a `chmod 777 ./db`, for testing)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `No suitable driver found for ${DATASOURCE_URL}` from the stacktrace it looks like the problem is that, at least for tests, your application is using an environment variable `DATASOURCE_URL` to get the DB url to connect to, and in your pipeline you don't have it defined.

One way to define it is by adding a step with an export to the script:

```yaml
image: gradle:7.6.0-jdk17

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-it
        name: Build project
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - export DATASOURCE_URL='jdbc:sqlite:file:./db/mydb.db?cache=shared'
          - bash ./gradlew build
          
        artifacts:
          - 'build/**'
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build-it
```

Comment: thanks. I am sorry that I pasted the wrong stack trace, you were correct here that the error shows `DATASOURCE_URL` variable is missing, I actually fixed that.  I updated my post again, could you please check my updated full stack trace again? It is merely the database file is not able to be opened.